# How to sum total of elements in several columns of factor type that are not empty?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Provided a data frame like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(list(Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2"),
                      A=c("Some text", "Text here too", "Some other text", NA), 
                      B=c(NA, "Some random text", NA, "Random here too")))
> df
   Group               A                B
1 Group1       Some text             <NA>
2 Group1   Text here too Some random text
3 Group2 Some other text             <NA>
4 Group2            <NA>  Random here too
```

I would like to sum all values in columns `A` and `B` that have some values and then sum them per each group independently, resulting in the following data frame:

```
> df.expected
   Group A_n B_n
1 Group1   2   1
2 Group2   1   1
```

Although this is a silly data frame example (the original data frame has far more columns and groups and it's not so easy to manually achieve the results), I am not succeeding due to the fact that I can't operate with factors. Additionally, I'm afraid my approach (see below) is too verbose and maybe overkill, and it makes it not very suitable for my real data frame, with far more columns.

That's what I've done so far:

```
# Manually create a new numeric column with numbers.
df$A_n = as.character(df$A)
df$A_n[!is.na(df$A_n)] <- 1
df$A_n = as.numeric(df$A_n)

df$B_n = as.character(df$B)
df$B_n[!is.na(df$B_n)] <- 1
df$B_n = as.numeric(df$B_n)
```

This part is working fine, although I'm afraid there might be a better and shorter/semiautomated way to create new columns and assign them a value. Maybe it's even unnecessary.

The second part of my code is aimed to group the observations according to a grouping variable and sum the values in each variable using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)  

df2 = df %>% 
      select(Group, A_n, B_n) %>% 
      group_by(Group) %>% 
      summarise_all(sum)
```

However, I am getting unexpected data frame:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   Group   A_n   B_n
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group1     2    NA
2 Group2    NA    NA
```

Can anyone help me in how to tackle this problem in a better way and/or tell me what am I doing wrong with dplyr's code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What am I doing wrong with dplyr's code block?

It's because there are `NA`s. Try

```
library(dplyr)  

df2 = df %>% 
      select(Group, A_n, B_n) %>% 
      group_by(Group) %>% 
      summarise_all(sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

instead.

Output on my machine:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   Group   A_n   B_n
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group1     2     1
2 Group2     1     1
```

## I'm afraid my approach ... is too verbose and maybe overkill

You can just do this:

```
df <- data.frame(list(Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2"),
                      A=c("Some text", "Text here too", "Some other text", NA), 
                      B=c(NA, "Some random text", NA, "Random here too")))

library(dplyr)

df2 = df %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise_all(.funs=function(x) length(na.omit(x)))
```

Output on my machine:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   Group     A     B
  <fctr> <int> <int>
1 Group1     2     1
2 Group2     1     1
```

#### A little explanation

If you look at `help(summarise_all)`, you'll see its arguments are `.tbl`, `.funs`, and `...` (which we won't worry about the ellipses for now). So, we feed `df` into `group_by()` using the pipe `%>%`, then feed that into `summarise_all()`, again using the pipe `%>%`. That takes care of the `.tbl` argument. The `.funs` argument is how you specify what function(s) should be used to summarise to all non-grouping columns in `.tbl`. Here we want to know how many elements of each column is not `NA`, which we can do (as one approach) by applying `length(na.omit(x))` to each non-grouping column `x` in `.tbl`.

My best suggestion for a resource to learn about `dplyr` is [Chapter 5 of R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html), a book by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley), who wrote the `dplyr` package (among many others).

Comment: Thank you! It works like charm, but to be honest, I do not understand what you are doing in summarise_all as I am not familiar at all with the dot, nor funs... could you please address me somewhere I can read/learn about it?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll edit my answer in an hour to include additional explanation with links.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `aggregate` with the standard interface (as opposed to the formula interface).

```
aggregate(cbind(A_n=df$A, B_n=df$B),  df["Group"], function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
   Group A_n B_n
1 Group1   2   1
2 Group2   1   1
```

`cbind` the variables to be calculated and provide there names. In the second argument, include the grouping variables. Then, as you function, sum over na indicator of elements that are not missing.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time in answering this question. I prefered the other answer as I am much more familiar with dplyr syntax and because it requires typing less columns' names, which is an extra point since I have quite some columns.